# Add new page while generating pdf from html with dynamic content

Tags: angular, typescript, html2canvas, pdfmake

I'm trying to generate pdf from html with dynamic content using `pdfmake`. its working good but having an issue.

Html content is to large and pdf only generating one page and rest of the content from html is cut. How can I add other page to pdf if content is more than one page.

Here is my code.

```
createPdf(): void {
     var main = $('.main');
    html2canvas(this.el.nativeElement, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();                       
                var a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89];
                var docDefinition = {
                    pageSize: 'A4',
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500,
                        pageBreak:'after'
                    }],
                     pageBreakBefore: function(currentNode, followingNodesOnPage,
                      nodesOnNextPage, previousNodesOnPage) {                      
                       return currentNode.headlineLevel === 1 && followingNodesOnPage.length === 0;
                    }
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
            },
            imageTimeout:2000,
            removeContainer:true
        },
        );
    }
```

there was some suggestion to use `pageBreakBefore` but I don't know how to use it in my case.

Please suggest me a way here.

Comment: Try to add `pageBreakBefore` to `content`.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Tried like this to use `pageBreakBefore` in updated question. but not working. Can you look into it and tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you create an image from canvas and add this image to pdf document. Surely this image will not be broken into several parts / pages. And this huge image is cut. The only thing you can do to make it fit the page is to set the image size the page size, but you will get unreadable content. It is not what you need. And pagebreakBefore will not help you. As you cannot break one image into several parts.

What we do is creating an object with data and pass it to pdfmake. Then the content is passed to the next page automatically. Issues arise only with images when an image is rendered close to the footer or with long dynamic content and then this pageBrealBefore helps us. Not your case again.

So, you will have to read content of html elements and dynamically add it one by one to text field in that dynamic object (play with it on the pdfmake playground) and then everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I can get HTML content by its div . But it's height is not fixed . So I'm not sure how can content be fixed in page. Can you suggest a way in my case?

Comment: so, do you suggest creating object of data with different canvas images and pass to `pdfmake` ? Any other way to put content to pdf without converting it to canvas image?

Comment: No, do not create any images. Get the text content of the elements, create an object, dynamically add data and send this object to pdfmake. It will pass data to the new page automatically. Again, do not create images from html. Just get text data like here: http://pdfmake.org/playground.html  Push objects with text data { 
   text: 'This is a header ', 
   style: 'header' 
  } to the content array.

Comment: Html content have image how can it work with text data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get text data from html to `{ text: 'This is a header ', style: 'header' }`

Comment: It depends on your project. As an idea, document.querySelectorAll will get you elements. Then iterate through the array and get text content of each text element and at once create var obj = { text: someTextContent, style: 'header' } and do content.push(obj); That is all.

Comment: well, there are many images and styling is very important. that's why I'm using canvas to create image of the content. you can have a look at my site 
http://180.211.120.106/wingsts/ts/travelz/ I need pdf of all these content

Comment: you can add your images the same way as the text. create dynamic objects and add them to the content array. But set the width not to be larger than page width. see pdfmake playground how to do it. and if you want it to be to one as in your html, I am afraid you will not achieve it. Or you will have to make image from canvas of html which is on one page, add it to pdf and do the same with the next page of your html.

Comment: yes, that's why I was using canvas but if contents height is more then it cuts from page

Comment: If it is necessary for you to keep to this exactly view and use images, then reuse canvas to cut that big image into many that fit the page height. You can check the approximate height of a4 page and create one more canvas with the needed height and width and put there you big image using canvas methods, cutting it into several images in succession.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149458/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-peter-babukh).

Comment: how can I cut canvas image into many? After cutting canvas images . its possible to add that image to new page?

Comment: If the image is the pdf page height, it will be passed to the next page automatically in case of not fitting it. There are issues with it, but generally it works. Your big image is too big for one page, so it is cut. But yes, the challenge is how to cut it. I did not do it. I do not know how to do it with canvas. Maybe it is impossible. Google some other ways if any to do it. We just used text added dynamically to the content, as i wrote above, including html images. When they are smaller than page size, they will be passed to the next page by pdfmake.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for your help. I will try google and check it

Comment: do you have any idea about `proxy` in `html2canvas`?

Comment: Too late for answer, though the answer is 'no' anyway. Also interested in which way you solved it.

Comment: created object of `data` and added it to `dd`